# A conjecture about Euler's function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I am reading Sierpinski's book: Elementary theory of number, 1988.

In that book has the following problem (page 254):

**Problem.** Prove that for arbitrary natural numbers $a,b$ there exist infinitely many pairs of natural numbers $x,y$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{\varphi (x)}{\varphi (y)}=\frac{a}{b}.$

*Solution in the book.* Without loss of ganerality we may assume that $\gcd (a,b)=1$. Let $x=a^2b(kab+1),y=ab^2(kab+1)$, here $k$ is a positive integer, then $\displaystyle \frac{\varphi (x)}{\varphi (y)}=\frac{a}{b}.$

This is my question.

**Conjecture.** For arbitrary natural numbers $a,b$ there exist infinitely many pairs of natural numbers $x,y$ such that $\gcd (x,y)=1$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\varphi (x)}{\varphi (y)}=\frac{a}{b}.$

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you come up with this conjecture?

Comment: Is it obvious that the conjecture is true when $a=b$? I'm not sure if, for example, $p-1 = (q-1)(r-1)$ has infinitely many solutions, where $p,q,r$ are distinct primes.